# Problem installing Z3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, mono

I downloaded Z3 from https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 on Ubuntu 16.04, but the compiled file **microsoft.z3.dll** is installed in the project directory instead of the mono or GAC folder, and the programs do not recognize it (**microsoft.z3.dll** is placed in `z3-master/build/` instead of `/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/`).

These are the instructions I used to install Z3:

1. Install the package repository of the mono project as described at their download page, and then:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel

sudo apt-get install nuget
```

2. Download the current stable release from Z3 releases, and then:

```
CSC=/usr/bin/csc GACUTIL=/usr/bin/gacutil python scripts/mk_make.py --dotnet

cd build

make

sudo make install
```

Please advise me how to install the file **microsoft.z3.dll** elsewhere or how to move the installed file **microsoft.z3.dll**.

Comment: Why don't you install it from the **nuget** repository? Try ```dotnet add package Microsoft.Z3.x64 --version 4.8.8```.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi  Mr Mousavi, You are right. I asked the author at GitHub and he gave the same answer. But when I type this command in the terminal, it gives this error. ```Could not find any project in `/home/madieh/`.```
``` dotnet add <PROJECT> package [options] <PACKAGE_NAME>```
Can you help me?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi  This is an author comment on GitHub, but I do not understand it correctly.  

(The mentions of GAC/CSC seems stale. It now builds a nuget package, also present in the nighly builds and published on nuget.org. You should use the nuget utilities to install. I have removed stale mentions of CSC and GAC in the readme.)

I am very new in Ubuntu.

Comment: You have to run that command inside your project directory(or add your ```.csproj``` file as the second argument to ```dotnet add``` i.e ```dotnet add /path/to/yourproject.csproj package Microsoft.Z3.x64 --version 4.8.8```)  and the required ```.dll``` file plus required runtimes(for **MacOS** , **Linux** and **Windows**) will be added by default to the ```~/.nuget/packages``` directory.Then whenever you add that dependency to your projects,given the same version of **Z3**,it won't need to be re-downloaded.Packages in the ```~/.nuget/packages``` is somehow global(Not to be confused with GAC)

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Mr. Mousavi, I really apologize for bothering you. If I were not so helpless, I would not bother you. There is a project in GitHub and I have to run it (that is, the code is not for me).
I did what you said and the following error was shown:
```rror: Error while adding package 'Microsoft.Z3.x64' to project '/home/madieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj'. The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.```
Thank you very much if you can help me

Comment: No problem.If you just want to run a project from github,just go the source directory(the directory which contains the ```.csproj``` file) and then run ```dotnet build ; dotnet run```.It would install all the required packages automatically for you and then launches the program.I thought you wanted to install Z3 to use with your own project and also you didn't mention in the question you want to run the project **Spire**.Although your problem here is entirely a different question than of the original one.But hope it helps.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Mr. Mousavi, Sorry again, I used the command you said and the following error was displayed:

```/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.302/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/home/madieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
```

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I installed Wine and used it to install .NETFramework v4.5.2  Developer Pack. The same error was displayed again.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi  I asked my questions several times in the stackoverflow and askUbuntu, and you were the only one who answered me.